# No JSON object could be decoded (although data does exist)

Tags: html, json, python-2.7, urllib2

I am new to JSON. I ran the code below and got an error

```
import urllib2
import json
urllib2.urlopen('https://ciapipreprod.cityindextest9.co.uk/TradingApi')
print json.load(urllib2.open(`https://ciapipreprod.cityindextest9.co.uk/TradingApi'))
```

`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

But when I ran it without json as below, I could see what was inside.

```
import urllib2
data=urllib2.urlopen('https://ciapipreprod.cityindextest9.co.uk/TradingApi')
html = data.read()
print html

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>Ajax Test Harness</title>

<link href="/TradingAPI/Content/css?v=oI5uNwN5NWmYrn8EXEybCIbINNBbTM_DnIdXDUL5RwE1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/TradingAPI/Content/themes/base/css?v=M29VGAPKJl__Ya5hV5ngguUfY8uNXwB076bG-JmFavY1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/TradingAPI/Scripts/js?v=lYEohN8Pq3__VMPgz6C4ZXSyFUc0d6gVJQ28Wflqo3E1"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0px;">            

        <img alt="CityIndex Logo" src="/TradingAPI/Images/ci_white_logo.jpg"/>

</div>
<h2>Ajax Test Harness</h2>

<script src="/TradingAPI/Scripts/tradingApi.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/TradingAPI/Scripts/corsTest.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/TradingAPI/Scripts/json2.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="apitest">

<form id="form1" runat="server"></form>

<hr />
<h2>Test Harness</h2>

<button onclick=" eval($('#code').val()); ">Execute</button><br />

<textarea id="code" cols="120" rows="15">

    var userName = "DM631479";

    doPost('/session',{ "UserName": userName, "Password": "password"}, function (data, textCode) {    

        // Smoke Test

        doGet('/smoketest');



        setRequestHeader("UserName", userName);

        setRequestHeader("Session", data.Session);



        // Authentication Test

        doGet('/smoketest/authenticated');



        // Account Information Tests

        doGet('/useraccount/DM631479/ChartingEnabled');

        doGet('/useraccount/ClientAndTradingAccount');

        // Need Valid Test Data doPost('/useraccount/Save', {"PersonalEmailAddress":"not@realaddress.com","PersonalEmailAddressIsDirty":true})



        // Cfd Markets Test

        doGet('/cfd/markets?marketname=uk&maxresults=10&usemobileshortname=true');



        //Logoff

        doPost('/session/deleteSession?userName='+userName+'&session='+data.Session);

    });

    /* var userName = "DM631479";

        cityindex.corsTesting.doPost('/session',{ "UserName": userName, "Password": "password"}, function (data, textCode) {    

        });*/

    </textarea>

<br />

<select id="result" style="background-color: #e4e4e4; min-height: 300px;" multiple="multiple"></select>

<hr />

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

My understanding was that if there were '{}' within my var 'Data' they were "dictionaries" and I could then call them using the JSON module.

Perhaps I have misread the contents of my variable and maybe there actually isn't anything for JSON to 'load'

Sorry if any of the tagging here is wrong or ineligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like that url returns html, and not json at all. Also, from the print statement, results it doesn't look like there is any json embedded in the page at all.

json.load will only work with input that looks exactly like json, something that looks like a dictionary. It won't pull this out of the surrounding html.

If there were json somewhere on that page, say, in a script tag, the you'd first have to parse the html to extract it. You could use beautiful soup or scrapy for that.

Answer (score 0):

JSON has [a particular *specified* shape](http://www.json.org/) which that response does not conform to.  What you have there is JavaScript (and some JavaScript is valid JSON) embedded in HTML.  It's similar to this example:

```
<pre><code>print("Hello World")</code></pre>
```

which *contains* Python code, but is not, in total, valid Python code.  In order to extract the data you will need to find a different endpoint to hit that produces valid JSON (or else you will have to extract the JSON-like parts of the JavaScript on the page that you are interested in by using the [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) built into the standard library, a library like [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or regular expressions).  Then you can feed the valid JSON text to `json.loads` and work with it.